# Index out of range exception vs argument out of range exception

Tags: c#, exception, indexing, arguments, range

When working from a list object, checking against an index that is out of range, for example

```
List<MyObject> allServices = new List<MyObject>();
var indexOf = 0;

lnkBack.NavigateUrl = allServices[indexOf - 1].FullURL;
```

Where I would think it would throw an index out of range exception, it throws an argument out of range exception.  Why is this, when it's an index we're testing against?

I'd expect argument if it was something like the substring method where substring(-1) would be an argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays and list both inplement `IList<T>` which throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead of an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when you try to access an item at a negative index:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewthkb10(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:     **index is not a valid** index in the `IList<T>`

You can reproduce it with this code:

```
IList<string> test = new string[]{ "0" };
string foo = test[-1];  // ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

If you use it as `string[]` you get your expected `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
string[] test = new string[]{ "0" };
string foo = test[-1];  // IndexOutOfRangeException
```

That's the reason why it throws the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` of `IList<T>` instead of the `IndexOutOfRangeException` of array.

Comment: I think the last statement is backwards. `IList<T>.this[int]` throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and array throws `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @DavidLechner: thanks, fixed it, better late than never ;)

Comment: Having just wasted a bit of time due to the same issue, I was hoping to find a rationale for the obvious follow-on question of "why does IList<T> specify ArgumentOutOfRangeException rather than the seemingly more appropriate IndexOutOfRangeException in this scenario?". Clearly it's too late to change now as lots of existing code relies on it... but frustrating nevertheless to have an answer that just amounts to "because that's the way it is".

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the list as an array is just a syntax feature. What happens behind the scene is that the code uses the [`Item` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), sending the index as the argument.